# "object is not a function" in YouTube iframe player API

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm developing a service using YouTube Player API.
But, I get an error in playing some videos. (almost all videos have no problem)
Because this code is complex, I tried playing target video in YouTube official DEMO. I got a same error.

Environment:
Windows 7 / Chrome 36.0.1985.125 m

Error Message:
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function : www-embed-player.js:310
( https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vfl385XVN/www-embed-player.js )

How to reproduce:

- Access https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo
- Display console window of Chrome for debug.
- Enter "`RDHBkza_ZcI`" in [Content:][video ID]. (other parameters are default)
- Push the button [Update player with selected options].

  - Console display error message and the player start **Demo video**. (not "`RDHBkza_ZcI`")
- If you push the button [Update player with selected options] again, player will start "`RDHBkza_ZcI`".

Question:

1. What is this error?
2. Why happen this problem?
3. Is there solution?

Comment: It may be defect, I reported gdata-issues. https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6576